# absolute positioned :before pseudo element take the focus of a child link

Tags: html, css, dom, hyperlink, pseudo-element

I have a little issue with a pseudo element which not propagate correctly the click and the hover on a brother link (same parent). Here the problem

The html is a div containing different buttons and a text and link in a child div and a logo in background which overflowing the div :

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
     <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <div class="super-link">
     <span />
     <a href="/#/stuff" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And the style (**sass style**) :

```
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
    &:before {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        bottom: -35%; right: -35%;
        width: 110%; height:110%;
        background-image: url('../img/logo.svg');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        opacity:0.1;
    }

    .super-link {
        span {
            // ...
        }
        a {
            // ...
        }
    }
 }
```

*I'll try to provide a fiddle*, but with that, does anyone has the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact I found the solution even if I'm not fully understanding what's happen here :

```
.super-link {
   display:inline-block; // or block
   position:relative;
}
```

Make the link go upon the :before element (positioned absolutly).